# Find the indicated term of the geometric sequence algebraically.

Tags: geometric-series

a1=18, r=4/3, 8th term

1.Find the indicated term of the geometric sequence algebraically.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What do you know about geometric series that might be useful in solving this problem?

Comment: I know first term is 18, and difference is 4/3. We need to find 8th term so we?

Comment: Let's start with something a little simpler. How would you find the second term?

Comment: multiple 18 with 4/3

Comment: second term is 24

Comment: Exactly! If you had to multiply by $4/3$ once to find the second term and twice to find the third term, how many times would you need to multiply by $4/3$ to find the eighth term?

Comment: 8? So do I multiply 24 times 4/3 for third term etc?

Comment: Is the answer is 60?

Comment: If you have a G.P. then $a_1=18,a_2=18\cdot\dfrac 43, a_3=18\cdot(\dfrac 43)^2,\cdots,a_8=18\cdot(\dfrac 43)^7$

Comment: You were close with your guess of $8$. Notice that
$$a_\color{red}1=18\times\left(\frac43\right)^\color{red}0=18\times1=18$$
$$a_\color{red}2=18\times\left(\frac43\right)^\color{red}1=18\times\frac43=24$$
I was about to ask if you could continue that pattern on your own to see why you would need to multiply by $4/3$ only $7$ times to find the eighth term, but it looks like someone else beat me to it.

Comment: 294912/2187?, so like 134.99?

Comment: Yep, that's it. I got $134.85$, but it's pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize what transpired in the comments:

Notice that
$$a_\color{red}1=18\times\left(\frac43\right)^\color{red}0=18\times1=18$$
$$a_\color{red}2=18\times\left(\frac43\right)^\color{red}1=18\times\frac43=24$$
$$a_\color{red}3=18\times\left(\frac43\right)^\color{red}2=18\times\frac{16}9=32$$
$$\dots$$
Continuing the pattern a few more times, you'll find that
$$a_\color{red}8=18\times\left(\frac43\right)^\color{red}7=18\times\frac{16384}{2187}\approx134.85$$
Problems like this become much simpler if you can find a pattern!